# how to return an object form the mongodb resultant while in asyn calls

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, promise

i am not getting the perfect result though i used promise in my project, some times the `getSubCats` function is returning the empty object and some times that function returning the resultant of `subCategories`

### what i tried

```
exports.getCatsVthSubcats = function (req, res) {
  var catsArray = [];

  Category.find({active:true}).exec(function (err, cats) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error  : " + JSON.stringify(err))
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        var catId = cats[i].catId;
        catsArray.push(getSubCats(catId));
      }
      Promise.all(catsArray).then(results => {
        console.log("REULT : " + JSON.stringify(results))
      })

    }
  })
}

function getSubCats(catId) {

  return SubCats.find({
    catId: catId,
    active: true
  }).exec(function (err, subCategories) {
      var obj = {
        catId: catId,
        subcats: subCategories
      }
      return obj;   
  })
}
```

### what iam getting the result

```
console.log(catsArray )
    [ 
      [
       {
         category : "vegitarian",
         rank : 23
       },
       {
         category : "Non-vegitarian",
         rank : 2
       }
      ],
      [],  // some times getSubCats function returning empty array
      [
       {
         category : "appetizers",
         rank : 3
       },
       {
         category : "nonveg-appitizers",
         rank : 52
       }
      ]

    ]
```

### what i want

```
 console.log(catsArray )
        [ 
          { catId : Vegitarian,
           subcat :[
                    {
                      category : "vegitarian",
                      rank : 23
                    },
                    {
                     category : "Non-vegitarian",
                     rank : 2
                    }
                  ]
            },
            { catId : "Non-vegetarian",
              subcats :[
                        {
                         category : "appetizers",
                         rank : 3
                        },
                        {
                         category : "nonveg-appitizers",
                         rank : 52
                        }
                      ]
               }

        ]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this result, because you're using `Model.find` (returns an array of objects), when you need to use `Model.findOne` (returns single element or null).

Besides of this your code could be simplified. You shouldn't mix callbacks  style and promises:

```
exports.getCatsVthSubcats = (req, res) => {
  Category
    .find({ active: true })
    .then(cats => {
        let catIds = cats.map(cat => cat.catId);
        return Promise.all(catIds);
    })
    .then(results => console.log("REULT : " + JSON.stringify(results)))
    .catch(err => console.log("Error  : " + JSON.stringify(err)));
}

function getSubCats(catId) {
  return SubCats
      .find({
        catId: catId,
        active: true
      })
      .then(subcats => {
          var obj = {
            catId: catId,
            subcats
          }
          return obj;   
      });
}
```